Remove border of the Legend of Chart
I have a multiAxisChart with a couple of charts. I wrote a JRChartCustomizer for each chart and tried to JFreeChart.getLegend() which returned null. I tried getting CategoryPlot.getLegendItems() which returns values. But there is no method with 'border' in LegendItem.
I just want to remove the border from the single legend displayed for both the charts.

You might look at the BlockBorder of your LegendTitle, seen here.

I had a lineChart and barChart.  getLegend() returned null for barChart but worked for lineChart and got the border color set with LegendTitle.

Based on this example, I got the LegendTitle from the lineChart's chart object in customizer and set the Frame with BlockBorder object matching the background color. Thus, the legend border is not shown.
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setFrame(new BlockBorder(Color.WHITE));

